# Bokeh, standalone html, access to the div created by a CustomAction to add the style bk-active

Tags: bokeh

I've used 2 objects from CustomAction to add 2 buttons to the toolbar : it works fine (with javascript callback), but now, i would like to show / hide the little blue line under those button when the corresponding tool is activated (=adding the style 'bk-active' to the div corresponding to those buttons) : how to do that ? Is it possible to add a html id to the CustomAction ? or how to get an access to the html div on the javascript side through the Bokeh object or cb_obj or this ?
(it's a standalone file, no server)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have just one Bokeh document you could give your `Div` a `name` attribute and use: `var div = Bokeh.documents[0].get_model_by_name('div_name')` in JS callback. See example below (works for Bokeh 2.1.1)

```
from bokeh.models import Div, Button, Column, CustomJS
from bokeh.plotting import show

button = Button(label='Toggle Div Visibility')
div = Div(text = 'Bokeh Div', name = "bokeh_div")

# code = "if (div.visible == true) { div.visible = false; } else { div.visible = true; }"
# button.js_on_click(CustomJS(args = {'div': div}, code = code))

code = "var div = Bokeh.documents[0].get_model_by_name('bokeh_div'); 
        if (div.visible == true) { div.visible = false; } else { div.visible = true; }"
button.js_on_click(CustomJS(code = code))

show(Column(button, div))
```

Comment: Thanks for this help, i already know this technic but with it, we have an access to a bokeh object, not the html object, so not possible to change the style of the div of a CustomAction (not possible to add/remove the 'bk-active' style for example). I find surprising that it's not possible to add a html id to those items.

Comment: I see. It should be possible to get all `bk-active` div elements by using `document.querySelectorAll('div.bk-active')` but I don't advise manipulating DOM elements outside of Bokeh model. It would be better just to insert your own HTML `div` (not via Bokeh) element and manipulate it using JS.